# Rails api not accepting video uploads

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a rails api and I'm trying to setup a controller where you can upload a video. The way you upload this video is using form-data. I have tried different methods of getting my video to save but nothing works. This could be a problem with the params, but I'm not 100% sure. When I run `if @video.save` it returns false, always. In the post request I am sending an Id (for user id), a description, and in the form-data I am sending a mov video (I have set validation to video/quicktime). Here is the controller that I am sending the info to:

**uploads_controller.rb**

```
class UploadsController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json
  before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:create]
  protect_from_forgery with: :null_session

  def create
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @video = Video.new(video_params)
    if @user == current_user
      if @video.save
        render :create 
      else
        render json: {status: 'Video could not save'}, status: :not_found
    else
      render json: {status: 'Invalid token'}, status: :not_found
    end
  end

  private

  def video_params
    params.permit(:clip, :description, :id)
  end
end
```

I am also using activestorage to upload these videos into s3. The error from the console (after sending the post request) is `Rendered ActiveModel::Serializer::Null with Has`

Comment: why don't you output the errors from the model `status: @video.errors.full_messages.join(', ')` that way you can debug the problem

Comment: Doesn't give me much. In the rails console it simply says ```completed 0``` and in postman shows the status as CUSTOM.

Comment: ok, maybe the problem is in the `video_params` method, if you're using `form_for` to build the form maybe you need to permit params in this way `params.require(:video).permit(:clip, :description, :id)` ... it's just a guess, maybe you can edit your question and add the form to see how the params should look like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured it out. The correct controller params is: `params.require(:video).permit(:clip, :description)`. Your also supposed to change the post request because the old one wouldn't work so it would look like this:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "video": {
        "description": "Diss"
    }
}
```

And then you would insert the video in form-data. You can't easily accomplish this in Postman though, so you would have to find another way of sending that.

Edit: There is no way of testing this solution that is easily done, so I'm not 100% sure about it.